# Autorelease CFMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, autorelease, cfmutabledictionary

How do I autorelease a CFMutableDictionary?

I'm creating it like this:

```
self.mappingByMediatedObject = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
```

And in dealloc:

```
self.mappingByMediatedObject = nil;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreFoundation doesn't have a notion of autorelease-- that's a Cocoa-level construct. However, for the objects that are ["toll-free" bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002401-767858) across worlds like strings and the collection classes, you can get the same result by casting the CF reference to its corresponding Cocoa reference, and sending it the `-autorelease` message, like this:

```
[(NSDictionary *)aDictionaryRef autorelease];
```

In your case, though, you might not really want to use autorelease here, because you're not handing back the reference for a Cocoa caller. Why not be a little more explicit around your allocation instead and just releasing it after setting it, like this:

```
CFDictionaryRef mapping = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
self.mappingByMediatedObject = mapping;
CFRelease(mapping);
```

Comment: Actually this does not work as I cannot use retain as a property attribute because the value (CFMutableDictionary) is not an object, so doing this causes the instance to be collected immediately. But that is just the specifics of my situation and not what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

`CFDictionary` and `NSDictionary` are toll-free bridged. This means the CoreFoundation object and its Cocoa counterpart are interchangable.

So to autorelease a `CFDictionary` you can write the following:

```
CFDictionary dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(...);
self.mappingByMediatedObject = dict;
[(NSDictionary*)dict autorelease];
```

Of course autorelease the dictionary only if your `mappingByMediatedObject` property retains its value (`@property(retain)`)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS7 and Mac OS X 10.9 you can use the Core-Foundation auto release function CFAutorelease().